# Customize the xml generated for c# instances

Tags: c#

I am using XmlSerializer in c# to serialize a class instance to xml. By default, if I serialize the instance of following class:

```
public class XmlTest
{
    public bool b1;
}
```

the bool field is represented as `<b1>false</b1>` 
I have specific requirement that the value of bool fields be represented as elements as in `<false>` and `<true>` instead of text content. I have similar requirements for enum fields as well.

I have tried using attributes that control XML serialization but couldn't find one that meets my requirement. I am fairly new to c# and was wondering the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with the XML Serializer. You can use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) instead:

```
public XElement Serialize(XmlTest t){
    return new XElement("XmlTest",
                        new XElement(t.b1 ? "true" : "false"));
}
```

---

One hint on using LINQ to XML in an code generation setting: [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.aspx) has a [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341343.aspx) that looks very simple:

> ```
> public XElement(
>   XName name,
>   Object content
> )
> ```

but that `content` parameter can be [almost anything](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943882.aspx). That includes

> - Any type that implements [`ToString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/object.tostring.aspx)
> - Any type that implements [`IEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

So, for example:

> ```
> XElement xmlTree2 = new XElement("Root",
>     from el in xmlTree1.Elements()
>     where((int)el >= 3 && (int)el <= 5)
>     select el
> );
> ```

could produce

> ```
> <Root>
>   <Child3>3</Child3>
>   <Child4>4</Child4>
>   <Child5>5</Child5>
> </Root>
> ```

Comment: Hmm, this answer looks like it's closer to "the right way to do it" than mine - in fact mine might just dump the text, "true/false" and not create a new element

Comment: That seems good. But I think i haven't specified my complete use case. I am planning to auto-generate generate c# classes whose instances can then be serialized to xml. One option is to have a serialize method in every generated class and individually handle each field of the class. This doesn't sound very good. Better and my preferred approach will be to have a generic Serialize method that can take any instance as parameter. It can then use reflection to get fields of the class and depending upon their types, serialize them appropriately. Does that sound reasonable?

Comment: If you're auto-generating the classes, then you should be able to auto-generate the serialization code as well. I think you'll find LINQ to XML to be well-suited for that.

Comment: Thanks John, you have provided me with options that i can explore, refine and implement :-)